# How to upgrade to Python 3.7 in Linux centos from 2.7 in Compute Engine?

Tags: python, linux, google-compute-engine

Ive been trying to install Python3.7 by following this instruction to my compute engine instance. https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/

but everytime i try to check the version python3.7 --V it still not recognising my installation. And if i do python --version, it's still showing me python2.7

What's the best way to install python for the GCP compute engine' instance?

Thank you

Comment: What about `python3 --version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading default python on Linux is a very critical operation. Because most of the Linux functions uses python. So, upgrading would break those. But still, we can install the latest python versions through `make altinstall` command. It'll install the given version without replacing the default/existing version. You could find the binary at `/usr/local/bin/python3` or `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`.

> make altinstall is used to prevent replacing the default python binary
>   file /usr/bin/python.

If you installed python3 use `python3 --version` or `python3.7 --version` command to find out the version.

Comment: i created a new instance and install it from scratch again, and finally, it works this time :)